# Does a map between topologies determine a map between sets?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal{A})$ and $(Y,\mathcal{B})$ be Hausdorff spaces. Consider a function
\begin{equation*}
\phi:\mathcal{B}\rightarrow \mathcal{A}
\end{equation*}
which preserves inclusion, arbitrary unions, finite intersections, and satifies $\phi(\emptyset)=\emptyset, \phi(Y)=\phi(X)$.

Does there exist $f: X\rightarrow Y$ such that $\phi= f^{-1}$ ?

I know that if such an $f$ exists it is uniquely determined by $\displaystyle f^{-1}(y)=\bigcap_{O\in \mathcal{B},y\in O} \phi(O)$. I also know this gives an effective definition for $f$ satisfying $f^{-1}=\phi$ if
\begin{equation*}
\bigcup_{y\in O}\left(\bigcap_{O'\in \mathcal{B},y\in O'}\phi(O')\right)=\phi(O)
\end{equation*}
for all open sets $O\subset Y$. But I don't know if this is necesarily the case.

Comment: If there is such an $f$, then for any $y$, the set of $X_y=X\setminus\phi(Y\setminus\{y\})$ is the set of values $x\in X$ such that $f(x)=y$. The the question is, is it possible for two $y_1\neq y_2$ to have $X_{y_1}\cap X_{y_2}\neq \emptyset$, or, alternatively, is it possible that sucn an $f$ is not continuous?

Comment: +1, nice question. Where did you get this? :)

Comment: @IvoTerek I made it up ! My motivations come from category theory which I'm studying at the moment.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Because $Y\setminus \{y_{1}\} \cup Y\setminus \{y_{2}\}=Y$ you have $X_{y_{1}}\cap X_{y_{2}}=\emptyset$. What seems more difficult to me is that $\bigcup X_{y}=X$ since I do not assume $\phi$ preserves arbitrary intersections.

Comment: This might be related to the fact that $T_2$ spaces are sober, and the category of sober spaces is equivalent to that of _spatial locales_, that is, (the opposite of) lattices of open sets with maps as you defined. Check this [Wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_Heyting_algebra).

Comment: I also think no, and it being related to so-called "pointless topology".

Comment: Indeed it might have something to do, $\mathbb{N}$ with the cofinite topology is not sober and $\phi: F \mapsto F+1$ (on closed sets, not open ones) cannot be represented by a set function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to answer my own question, and I'm madly delighted to say the answer is yes, there always is such an $f$.

Note that for all $x\in X$ the set $\displaystyle N(x)=\bigcup_{O\in \mathcal{B}, x\notin \phi(O)}O$ has the form $Y\setminus\{y\}$. Indeed

- Suppose that $N(x)$ is all of $Y$. Then we would have $X=\phi(Y)=\phi(N(x))=\bigcup_{O\in \mathcal{B}, x\notin \phi(O)}\phi(O)$ and $x\notin X$ which is absurd.
- Suppose there were distinct $y_{1},y_{2}$ not in $N(x)$. Then there are two disjoint sets $O_{1},O_{2}$ containing $y_{1}$ and $y_{2}$ respectively. The sets $\phi(O_{1})$ and $\phi(O_{2})$ are disjoint so they cannot both contain $x$. Without loss of generality $x\notin \phi(O_{1})$ so that $O_{1}\subset N(x)$ and $y_{1}\in N(x)$ which is again absurd.

Define $f$ by letting $f(x)$ be the only element of $Y\setminus N(x)$. We have 
\begin{align*}
&x\in f^{-1}(U) \\
\iff &U \not\subset N(x) \\
\iff &x\in\phi(U)
\end{align*}
hence $f$ has the desired property.

I don't know what interpretations there might be of this in terms or pointless topology, or topos theory (I suggest this because it seems to me the proof has a propositional logical flavour).