# Defining homology groups directly from the topology

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Both simplicial and singular homology theories rely on 'model objects', simplexes or simplicial complexes, to define the homology groups of a topological space.

I was wondering if there is a way to define homology groups directly from the open set structure of a space $(X,\mathcal{T})$. Here's a formal formulation of my question:

*Is there a way to associate homology groups to bounded lattices with arbitrary joins so that $H_{n}(X)\simeq H_{n}(\mathcal{T})$, when seeing $\mathcal{T}$ as such a lattice ?*

Of course this needs some hypothesis on $X$, if only to convene on a definition for $H_{n}(X)$. I don't mind if strong assumptions on $X$ (compact Hausdorff, triangulable) are needed.

Note that if the answer is positive, then $(X,\mathcal{T})$ and $(Y,\mathcal{T}')$ would have the same homology groups whenever $\mathcal{T}\simeq \mathcal{T'}$. But this is not surprising since in fact $\mathcal{T}\simeq \mathcal{T'}$  implies $X\simeq Y$ assuming both spaces are Hausdorff; see my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1648186/does-a-map-between-topologies-determine-a-map-between-sets).

Comment: The set of open sets of a topological space is a category, which can be turned into a Grothendieck topology. The cohomology of the space can the be computed using homological algebra on the category of sheaves on that Grothendieck topology. This coincides with singular cohomology when the space is reasonable (paracompact, say)

Comment: Not sure why you were downvoted, I think it's a nice question!

Comment: I'd guess cosheaves on the Grothendieck topology should give homology under good circumstances, but I dunno.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez, your comment looks like why I wanted, even if it concerns cohomology and not homology. Do you have some reference developing what you said ? Preferably something suited for someone who just heard about Grothendieck topologies...

Comment: Tamme's book on etale cohomology is a great place to learn about Grothendieck topologies and their cohomologies, or Milne's notes on the subject. Both should establish the connection with sheaf cohomology on a topological space. From there you need to compare that with singular cohomology, and that's done in Bredon book on sheaves, if I recall correctly.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Many thanks ! If you want to write an answer I'll upvote it, and probably accept it if nothing else comes up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the construction of a (co)homology theory for lattices which yields the Čech (co)homology in the case of topological spaces when applied to the lattice of open subsets. Recall that the Čech theory works with open coverings. An analogue of an open covering in a lattice $L$ is a subset $C$ of $L$ satisfying the property that the join of the elements of $C$ equals the unique maximal element of $L$. (The assumption is that $L$ is bounded and has arbitrary joins.)
I will refer to such $C$ as a *covering* of $L$. I say that a covering $C$ of $L$  **refines** a covering $C'$ of $L$ if for each $c\in C$ there exists $c'\in C'$ such that $c\le c'$. A *refinement* of $C'$ is such $C$ together with a map $f: C\to C'$ 
$$
f: c\mapsto c', \quad c\le c'. 
$$
Given a covering $C$ of $L$ define its poset $P_C$ by taking meets of finite subsets of $C$. This poset yields a simplicial complex $X_C$, whose vertices are elements of $C$ and $c_0,...,c_n\in C$ define an $n$-simplex iff
$$
c_0 \wedge c_1 \wedge .... \wedge c_n\ne 0
$$
where $0$ is the least element of $L$.
The incidence relation between such simplices is the obvious one. Now, the Čech cohomology $H^*(L)$ (with coefficients in ${\mathbb Z}$) is defined as the direct limit
$$
\lim_{C} H^*(X_C)
$$
where the direct system is induced by the refinements of coverings $C$ of $L$. More precisely, if $(C,f)$ is a refinement of $C'$, we obtain a natural map of simplicial complexes
$$
\tilde f: X_C\to X_{C'}
$$
sending $c\in C$ to $f(c)\in C'$. Now, use pull-back map of the cohomology groups
$$
\tilde f^*: H^*(X_{C'})\to H^*(X_C).
$$
The direct limit of this direct system can be defined to be the Čech cohomology of $L$. One can define Čech homology similarly, using the homology and the associated inverse system instead of the direct one.

Comment: Your answer is very clear and exactly in the spirit of what I wanted, thanks a lot ! I'll work the details out when I begin (soon, hopefully) to study Cech cohomology seriously.

Comment: This is very interesting. Has there been any development of this idea? I know there are very general cohomology theories on Grothendieck topologies but it seems to me that nice stuff could come up by investigating this particular (co)homology on lattices

Comment: @Castor No idea.