# Simplicial approach to Cech cohomology?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, sheaf-cohomology, simplicial-stuff

Is there an entirely simplicial approach to constructing Cech cohomology? Maybe we can define what a "sheaf on a simplicial set" would mean and show that for any open cover $\{U_i\}$ and sheaf on a space $X$ there is a sheaf on the nerve of the open cover $\{U_i\}$ and go from there?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1682154/defining-homology-groups-directly-from-the-topology/1754983#1754983) and see if it does what you want.